# Complement of HAMPATH

Tags: complexity-theory, decision-problem

Is the complement of the [Hamiltonian Path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) known to be in $\mathsf{NP}$? I could not find explanations saying that it is, but then neither were there any claims saying that it is **not** in $\mathsf{NP}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The HAMPATH complement ("G does not contain an Hamiltonian path from s to t") is in [co-NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP); to be more precise it is  [co-NP complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP-complete) (it is easy to prove that $L$ is NP-complete if and only if its complement $\bar{L}$ is co-NP-complete).

The question if it is in NP is open.

But since HAMPATH is NP-complete, if its complement is in $\mathsf{NP}$ then $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{co\mbox{-}NP}$